How can I get the values of all raws of a column from a DataTable in C# when working with ADO.NET
the issue I'm facing is that in WPF and with using ADO.Net, I have a ComboBox, and I don't know how to add the Rows Values or Data of a column after Filling the result of the Select Query
into the DataTable, to the ComboBox.ItemsSource.
here's the code in C#:
DataTable dt_ProgrammingLanguages = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter sql_da_proglang = new SqlDataAdapter("sp_selectProgrammingLanguage", sqlConn);
sql_da_proglang.Fill(dt_ProgrammingLanguages);

cmb_ProgrammingLanguages.ItemsSource = dt_ProgrammingLanguages.Rows;

I hope someone can help me with that as soon as possible, and thank you all.
also, I've tried several more things and the result of them was filling the Combobox.itemsSource
with the values I want, but as chars, where every char is separated.
This is the full code:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace _5_WpfAppTraining5
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window_AddNew.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window_AddNew : Window
    {

        //static string sqlConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlConnStr"].ConnectionString;
        static private string sqlConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlConnStr"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnString);

        public Window_AddNew()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void cmb_ProgrammingLanguages_DropDownOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt_ProgrammingLanguages = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter sql_da_proglang = new SqlDataAdapter("sp_selectProgrammingLanguage", sqlConn);
            sql_da_proglang.Fill(dt_ProgrammingLanguages);

            cmb_ProgrammingLanguages.ItemsSource = dt_ProgrammingLanguages.Rows;
        }
    }
}


I hope someone can help me with that as soon as possible, and thank you all.

Working with a datatable is rarely a great plan. I recommend dapper. https://www.learndapper.com I would bind to a list of a class used specifically for this. With a combobox might use a record type if I just needed a couple of properties the record can be defined in one line. I would bind rather than set items source but you could use either. If you're going to do anything substantial in Wpf you should learn and use mvvm.

I love Datatables.   Try dt_ProgrammingLanguages.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field("abc") == "xyz").ToList();  or maybe dt_ProgrammingLanguages.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x["abc"] != DBNull.Value).ToList();

Thank you all, at the end, I've used loop to add each string item into the ComboBox, after trying lots of things. Thanks all.
